# How to set the time to each content should be shown after the site have already loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, plugins, effect

I'm looking for some plugin (js/ajax) or tutorial which let me set the time to each content should be shown after the site have already loaded.

For example:
I want my website with a loader and after that display the menu navigation (e.g. slide right to left effect), after the logotype, after the main image of home, etc.).

This website is a good reference for what I want: http://www.smog-bicyclettes.com/

Do you know something like this?

Comment: You can try window.onload = function() { setTimeout(function() {}, 1000); };

Answer (score 1):

Try using set timeout

```
 setTimeout(function(){
        /* Your Function */
    },2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm delegating deciding which animation to run to a single function `doAnimation` which maintains a counter of the last animation that ran.

We don't need to use setTimeout here because we're relying only on the jQuery animation callbacks to ensure one animation happens when another finishes.

Working example here (updated): http://jsfiddle.net/av8ZA/7/

HTML

```
<div id="element1"></div>
<div id="element2"></div>
<div id="element3"></div>
<div id="element4"></div>
<div id="element5"></div>
<div id="element6"></div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    height:100px;
    width 200px;
    display:none;
}
#element1 {
    background: red;
}
#element2 {
    background: green;
}
#element3 {
    background: blue;
}
#element4 {
    background: magenta;
}
#element5 {
    background: black;
}
#element6 {
    background: yellow;
}
```

jQuery/Javascript

```
(function ($) {
    var currentCall = 0,
        animations = [{
            element: "#element1",
            type: "slide",
            options: {},
            time: 1000
        }, {
            element: "#element2",
            type: "blind",
            options: {}
        }, {
            element: "#element3",
        }, {
            element: "#element4",
            type: "size",
            time: 300
        }, {
            element: "#element5",
        }, {
            element: "#element6",
            type: "bounce"
        }],
        defaults = {
            type: "fade",
            time: 300,
            options: {}
        };

    function doAnimation() {
        if (animations[currentCall] != undefined) {
            var anim = animations[currentCall];

            $(anim.element).show(
            anim.type || defaults.type,
            anim.options || defaults.options,
            anim.time || defaults.time,
            doAnimation);
            currentCall++;
        }
    }

    $(document).ready(doAnimation);
})(jQuery);
```

Of course this is no good if you want concurrent animations, but you didn't state that in the question.

EDIT: I've cleaned up by javascript and defined an array of animations now where you can set options for each animation individually. For all animation types see the jQuery UI documentation for `show`. I've also defined some default that will be used if you don't specify one of the options for an animation.

Comment: Thanks, Matt!
Almost perfect! Do you know how can I try other animation effects?

Comment: @ico1984 Updated my answer for you!

Comment: @ico1984 Posted a new fiddle link for you!